# How to disable automatic start or tunnel activation on Windows startup?

Tags: windows, vpn, wireguard

I only found this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/fl7hvh/windows_10_disable_autostart_on_boot/) which suggests to disable the WireGuard Windows services. But those services seem to be automatically created when WireGuard ist started, or a tunnel activated.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this? Thanks.

Comment: @RyanPeters Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new answer on the reddit post:
"Activate the tunnel, then go into Windows Services, find the tunnel which will look like:
WireGuard Tunnel:. Open the properties of this service and set startup to 'manual'. Reboot and you should find the tunnel does not activate.
When you do want to start the tunnel, open the wireguard gui program and activate it."
The Windows Services are located in the Windows Services Manager (services.msc)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. The tunnel service only appears when tunnel is activated. I set it to 'Manual', but after a deactivate/activate cycle it is back at 'Automatic'.